# Programmatically fire dom delegated event

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have this dataview, with an event listener defined as:

```
listeners: [
    {
        element: 'element',
        delegate: '.listRow',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: function(a, b, c) {
            //do something
        }
    }
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically fire this event.

Comment: Have you tried [`Element.dom.click()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to fire the event. Do it like this:

```
var handleTap = function(a, b, c) {
    // do something
}

listeners: [
    {
        element: 'element',
        delegate: '.listRow',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: handleTap
    }
]

handleTap();
```

Comment: mm .. not exactly what I was asking, but I guess it works for the requirement. Thanks.